# How to make my project URL in github look like this?

Tags: github

I am new at github and I developed an application and I want to upload it to github and I am required to make the app accessible on a URL of the type :

```
http://githubusername.github.io/projectname/#/myapptitle
```

when I upload files on a new repository with the projectname I don't get the same structure as above. Please help I need to submit my project. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have look a github pages right here https://pages.github.com/. There is a very short step by step guide. Basically your repository has to be called: "githubusername.github.io"

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. We normally discourage answers which are primarily just a link. We prefer you provide a summary of the content as well; this archives the answer here in case the linked content changes or disappears. However, Github is a service which will change how it works. If the instructions were copied here they'd fall out of date and the answer would be wrong. So, in this case, your link-only answer is appropriate. (I'm also explaining this so others don't down vote a link-only answer)

Comment: @Schwern Thank you for explanation. I updated my answer. Have a nice day.